Freebsd: devd.conf, how can I find the proper matches?
Anyone know where or how to find the needed matches for an automation inside devd.conf? I am trying to run a script when the pppoe goes down.
This is what I have till now:
Code:
# Notify WAN 1 Down
notify 0 {
    match "system" "IFNET";
    match "subsystem" "pppoe0";
    match "type" "LINK_DOWN";
    action "/usr/local/bin/homeassistant/wan1_down.sh &";
};

The script wan1_down.sh it is working ok, I can run it manually, but I want this script to run it automatically, when the internet goes down.
Any idea?
It is about OPNsense (Which runs on freebsd)
Thanks!

Your code worked for me. Check that the interface name is correct and the script has "x" permission set.

Yes, I found the "error", the proper interface to use, is igc0, not pppoe0.
The new problem is that if I have two similar notify, only the one with higher priority will run, the other with low priority won't run. I thought that this priority option is to run the scripts secquentally, but seems that is is not so good :-(

You can see a trace ofdevd events by 1) stopping the devd daemon and running in foreground with -d, e.g.: devd -d 2>&1 | grep 'Processing event'
